# Hide status bar in all view controllers - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistatusbar

If I want to hide the status bar of a single view controller subclass then I do this:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

But what if I want to hide status bar by default in all view controllers subclass or not? Checking "Hide status bar" in the project settings does nothing.

I'm trying to program `UIPageViewController` which contains many view controllers attached to it. It would be nice not having to subclass them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your Info.plist file and add a new attribute:

`View Controller based status bar appearance` and set it to `NO`.

[image]

Then  go to App Delegate and replace your method to this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this is great. I can't mark your answer right now though. I think in about 7 mins.

Comment: Yes, of course... I am not in a hurry :-}}. I am glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks Bro for the answer , Upvoted :)

Comment: isn't this deprecated since iOS 9.0?

Comment: To be completely honest, I have no idea. Sorry. Anyway, this answer *was* posted back when ios 10 was the latest version available, and I recall it worked back then.

Answer (score 1):

right click your `Info.plist` and select `Open As > Source code`

at the end of the file, before

```
</dict>
</plist>
```

add this

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

or add `Status bar is initially hidden` and set it to `YES`